# TextBox Control Transparency / Picturebox Text

Tags: vb.net, textbox, controls, transparency

I have been wanted to create a custom text box and so I have found two methods which would allow me to achieve this although they aren't the best. One of the them is to actually draw text on the picturebox itself, but I wasn't able to find any tutorials or code to allow me to create this.

But I did find something for a Alpha channel textbox which although didn't allow me to put the control over other controls, I was able to work with it. The code works but my only problem now that is when other people use it the text is blurry.

Like this: http://puu.sh/4hzQM.png

This is how it looks like for me: http://puu.sh/4hzUD.jpg

I am currently using this code, which I converted to vb.net: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo

I was wondering if there is a way to fix this blurry text on other computers or if there is an easier way of doing this, because that code is 10 years old and everywhere I search, I can't find anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: If the code is 10 years old, you might find alternatives (even the functionalities you are after are already in VS). Just to make sure, the only thing of interest to you from this control is setting making a textBox transparent?

Comment: I want to make a custom text box and like I said, I only found out two methods, either make text draw on the picture box or make the textbox transparent instead so that you can see the picture below it. And yeah I wasn't able to find anything else apart from this. Maybe I searched for the wrong thing? Also I wasn't able to set the textbox transparent or find a way to have a custom text box in VS. Thanks.

Comment: You can change any control in VS. The quickest way is creating your own control by inheriting the target one (textbox in this case) and just modifying/adding the properties you wish. Let me do some tests and I can write a sample code as an answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your time. And yeah the code I posted does this as well, but I imagine there is an easier way which shorter code.

Comment: There you have the promised custom textbox. For sure that it is much simpler than the one you were using, but also much more reliable. Also you would understand perfectly how it is done, such that you can add/remove functionalities or, in general, getting more used to deal with this kind of things and to build codes completely by your own (VB.NET gives you lots of power to do many things).

Answer (score -1):

1. Add a class
2. insert this:

`Class TransparentControl
    Inherits Control
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        MyBase.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
        MyBase.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
        MyBase.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
        MyBase.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    End Sub
End Class
Class TransparentTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Both
    End Sub
    Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H20
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
        MyBase.Parent.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class`

1. Run your application
2. go to tool box, at the top you should see an item called "TransparentTextBox" add that, ignore the error
3. run app
4. enjoy