# Custom Control Blinks

Tags: vb.net, controls, richtextbox, transparent

I've managed to make a custom control which allows the RichTextBox background to appear transparent and it works almost perfectly but the only thing is, when the Rich Text box refreshes everything flashes/blinks. Everytime I type a letter all of my form refreshes and the text blinks as well as the form background image.

Is there any other way to update/refresh the text other than using

```
MyBase.Parent.Refresh()
```

This is my code:

```
Class TransparentRichTextBox
Inherits RichTextBox
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None
End Sub
Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H20
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
    MyBase.Parent.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I usually wait for sometime to see if anyone else replies. But back to the main topic at hand.

Comment: That has the same problem. The text doesn't update when you type, so you'd have to call a refresh method there also.

Comment: You are right. Apparently, making the RichTextbox transparent outputs a weird behaviour (cursor being constantly frozen). I have updated my code in my answer to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580767/textbox-control-transparency-picturebox-text); it is not a too elegant solution but, at least, it works. Regarding the blinking when you put it over a control whose background is an image, it seems to be provoked by the container control; you might have to restrict when its Paint Event is called.